# How to find componentid of wscript.shell?

Tags: powershell, com

I tried the following:

```
$obj = new-object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$obj | gm
```

which outputs:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{41904400-be18-11d3-a28b-00104bd35090}

Name                     MemberType            Definition
----                     ----------            ----------
AppActivate              Method                bool AppActivate (Variant, Variant)
CreateShortcut           Method                IDispatch CreateShortcut (string)
Exec                     Method                IWshExec Exec (string)
ExpandEnvironmentStrings Method                string ExpandEnvironmentStrings (string)
LogEvent                 Method                bool LogEvent (Variant, string, string)
Popup                    Method                int Popup (string, Variant, Variant, Variant)
RegDelete                Method                void RegDelete (string)
RegRead                  Method                Variant RegRead (string)
RegWrite                 Method                void RegWrite (string, Variant, Variant)
Run                      Method                int Run (string, Variant, Variant)
SendKeys                 Method                void SendKeys (string, Variant)
Environment              ParameterizedProperty IWshEnvironment Environment (Variant) {get}
CurrentDirectory         Property              string CurrentDirectory () {get} {set}
SpecialFolders           Property              IWshCollection SpecialFolders () {get}
```

If that's the case, then you should get a result for the following:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_ComClass | Where {$_.ComponentId -eq "{41904400-be18-11d3-a28b-00104bd35090}" }
```

However, I don't! Am I looking at the correct place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use WMI in this case. Just look for the ProgId (`Wscript.Shell`) directly in the registry:

```
HKCR\ProgId
```

If that key has a child key `CLSID`<sup>1</sup> then its default value is what you are looking for.

There are plenty of cases where a little more work is needed. Eg. : version independent ProgId's without a "CLSID" subkey, but with a "CurVer" subkey with another ProgId to lookup.

There are also cases where subkeys of HKCU (aka. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) don't represent COM classes that can be directly instantiated, these won't have a "CLSID" subkey.

Something like this should work (remembering that `HKCR:` is an alias for `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes`)

```
function getClsid {
  param(
    [string]$progId
  )

  if (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\$progId\CLSID") {
    (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\$progId\CLSID").{(default)}
  } elseif (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\$progId\CurVer") {
    $pp = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\$progId\CurVer").{(default)}
    getClsid -progId $pp
  } else {
    throw "Are you sure that's a ProgId?"
  }
}

getClsid -progId 'WScript.Shell'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> "Component Id" isn't a usual COM term, but CLSID (for "Class Id") is;  I think this is what you mean.

Comment: what does the `.{(default)}` mean? How to interpret it?

Comment: Putting braces (`{…}`) around a property name means the normal PSH identifier rules are bypassed: thus you can access, via this syntax, names with spaces and other characters not normally allowed. `(default)` is the name PSH inserts for the unnamed—default—value that each registry key can contain. (This is an artefact from the initial 16bit registry of Win3.x and Office when COM was first created. Named values were added with the move to 32bit.)